# Not getting "NotRegistered" response from Google even after uninstalling app from device in Google Cloud Messaging

Tags: android, notifications, google-cloud-messaging

I am working with Google Cloud Messaging. When I send a push notification to device I get a below success response from Google in the form of JSON

```
{"multicast_id":8671349350947963356,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1382106263047737%978fee92f9fd7ecd"}]}
```

Now when I have already uninstalled app from my device and its been been more than 28 hours, still it gives success response instead it should give "NotRegistered" response

```
{"multicast_id":8671349350947963356,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"error":"NotRegistered"}]}
```

Any Idea why Google not sending correct response ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It is sending the correct response, it's there in the results field results":[{"error":"NotRegistered"}]. What more do you want?

Comment: Did you try to send the notification multiple times after uninstalling the app?

Comment: NickT : Second response is what I am expecting but i m getting the first one only :) Any Idea ??

Comment: Eran yes i tried almost n number of times and its been almost 30 hours now it is still sending 1st response instead of which it should send 2nd response

Comment: @user45678 That's strange. Is it possible your device was turned off/disconnected from the internet after you uninstalled the app? GCM recognizes that the device is not registered for a given app only when a notification for that app reaches the device after the app is uninstalled.

Comment: Eran - No it wasn't off...The device is ON

Comment: Have a look into this : http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/adv.html Also you need to send device id to server so that server can remove your device id from database so next time you request you get NotRegistered error.

Comment: We're seeing the same results. Did you get anywhere with this? Uninstalled apps are still being returned as "success"

Comment: @Selsine...No luck...We had to drop this idea of identifying uninstalled device. I guess that major bugs from Google side

Comment: I'm having the same issue... Very strange

Comment: I don't think it's a bug per se (http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/adv.html#unreg) I just think that they are caching devices on their servers for longer. I think that the devices will eventually be removed.

Comment: selsine : But we never received error response...so its a bug...Caching can be temporary but its been so long now where we still receive "Success" message ;)

Comment: Does anyone has news regarding this issue?

Comment: Same issue here. 16 hours and counting, unregistered manually, and after 30 minutes uninstalled the application altogether, and still the push messages are being sent to the device, while the server gets "OK" message without the "NotRegistered" part. What the hell?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it is a known GCM server issue. See this Google Groups thread for more details and updated status:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-gcm/gScadiCjK-g

According to the thread, Costin Manolache had pushed a fix for the issue, but it was rolled back soon after. There doesn't appear to be a new ETA on an updated fix.

Comment: I'm one of the people who are discussing this there, and it really is very troubling how such a vital bug can go on for such a long time. Our server keeps sending push notifications to my device, WEEKS!!! after the app was uninstalled from my device. Unbelievable...